# (Discord.py) My command that gives roles to a user is not working

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to code it so that someone can give another person a role using a .role <@member>  command, so it'll look something like this:

`.role @Daily Cringe`

Ideally, the bot will give Daily the "Cringe" role. However, it is not working.

Here's the code:

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, member: discord.Member = ctx.author, role: discord.Role):
   await ctx.member.add_roles(role)
   await ctx.send(f"The role ''**{role}**'' was just given to you")
```

I tried to set the default value of `member` to `ctx.author` but then I get an issue:

```
async def role(ctx, member: discord.Member = ctx.author, role: discord.Role):
                   ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

I tried to change it so that the `role` variable's default value is equal to None, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas?

I use Visual Studio Code, Python 3.8.6 64-bit and MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several mistakes. At first, you can't do `member: discord.Member = ctx.author` because `ctx` is not defined yet. You have to set member's default value to **None** and check in the command if the member is **None**.

Then you can't add role with `ctx.member.add_roles(role)`. You have to do `member.add_roles(role)`.

```py
@client.command()
async def role(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, role: discord.Role):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    await member.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"The role ''**{role}**'' was just given to you")
```